# How to count the the data of specific two columns of different table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, pgadmin

I have two tables exactly having same column name but having different data or values. Now I want to count the total number of data of first column of table_1 union data of first column of table_2. How to do this?

```
____________________                ________________________
|    Table_1        |               |     Table_2           |
---------+----------                -----------+------------|
|arsc_lvl| Dist Name|               | arsc_lvl | Dist_Name  |
---------+----------                -----------+------------| 
|1       | Banke    |               | 5        | Bara       | 
|5       | Banke    |               | 7        | Bara       |
|6       | Bara     |               | 9        | Bara       |
---------+----------+               -----------+------------+ 

select count  ("arsc_lvl")
from "Table_1", "Table_2"
where
"arsc_lvl"<=10
```

this also did not provide me what I want.

I even used joins like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM [MyTable] Table_1
    INNER JOIN [MyOtherTable] Table_2
        ON Table_1."arsc_lv" = Table_2."arsc_lv"
```

It too didn't work for me. 
I got stuck here, please help.

Comment: Please show what should be the returned data for these tables. It's a bit unclear what you want as result.

Comment: my query should count the total number of arsc_lvl datas from both table. 
i mean:
3 from Table_1 + 3 from Table_2 = 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to count the number of rows in the union, so translate it into SQL:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM (SELECT * FROM table_1
      UNION
      SELECT * FROM table_2) u;
```

If you don't want to eliminate duplicates, use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`.

Comment: The way to express thanks here is to upvote and/or mark an answer as correct.

Answer (score -1):

select count(*),arsc_lvl from table1,table2;

Comment: sorry to say but this query dint worked either. anything more u can suggest, please?

Comment: i tried as you suggested but sorry to say it din't worked. i want to count specific column not whole table. i want my code to display the sum of counts of first column of table_1 and table_1. do you have any further ideas??

Comment: select count(id) from table; you can do it like this

Answer (score -1):

You can try this It worked for me. 
      select count(*) from tbl1 join tbl2 on tbl1.id = tbl2.id;

Comment: sorry to say but i cannot use  " * " because i want to just count arsc_lvl from first table plus arsc_lvl from second. 
both table have exactly same colum table name "arsc_lvl"  .
i tried using "arsc_lvl" insted of * again it dint worked.